# Randomly display line of text from .txt file | rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, text, random, devise

Basically I want to output a randomly chosen lines of text inside a .txt file. This is what I've come up with so far, but nothing gets really shown into onto the view. I've placed the questions.txt file inside of the posts view folder

**IN THE RAILS CONTROLLER:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def text_randomize
    t = IO.readlines("questions.txt")
    @random_question = t.sample
  end
end
```

**IN THE .TXT FILE:**

```
How are you?
How is the weather at your place?
How are you my pal?
I wish I was a donkey, do you?
How do you do?
```

**IN THE RAILS VIEW FILE:**

```
<div id = "questions">
  <%= @random_question %>
</div>
```

Have in mind that I use Devise as authentication, I'm telling you this because I've read that there are some catchy stuff going on when it comes to using the controllers, however I'm not entirely sure, therefore I'm only mentioning it.

So I'm not sure if I'm supposed to place the "ABOVE CONTROLLER" code in the helper file for posts or in the controller file for posts. Or somewhere else for that matter. 
In addition to this does somebody here have an idea on how to refer to an array from the helper file or the controller file?

I am able to randomly output a line of text right from the view, but I want to have in somewhere else, somewhere place more neat. Like in a file or in the helper or controller or something like that.

```
<%= ["Hello, how are you?", "How is the weather?", "Are you feeling good?"].sample %>
```

Thanks before you answer! :D

Comment: (BUMBING THIS QUESTION)(BUMP)(BUMP)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a model to do your random question logic.

I'll assume that you want to read the whole file into memory,
and select a random line.  It might be more efficient to somehow
randomize where in the file you will read, and read less of the file.
However, I don't suggest optimizing this until you have issues.

So, assuming you do want the file in memory, let's keep it in memory
and not have to go to the disk more than once.

```
class Question
  def self.random_question
    @all_questions ||= IO.readlines("questions.txt")
    @all_questions[rand(@all_questions.size)]
  end
end
```

Now you can call Question.random_question in the controller
and set it in an instance variable,
or even call it from the view, since the call is succinct enough.

Comment: Part of the design decision is that the role of your Question model might expand over time, and now you have a class which could instantiate a question object, if the questions become more complex.

Comment: Do I really need to create a new class for this? Can't I avoid that somehow? If I really can't how do you think I could use an array in the view from some other place more conveniently? Also why can't I do this in the controller? :S

Comment: No, you do not *need* to create a new class, it's a better design if you do.  You can get it to work with code in the controller, view, or helper, but the best place for it would be in the models.  This is conforming the MVC pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: ahem ahem, remember I'm on noob level here, so really I've only placed it in the controller do I now have to add some extra code to the one you supplied to me?

Comment: undefined method `random_question' for #<Class:0x3252cc0>. **EDIT** REMOVED the error, but no text shows up.

Comment: Well, work on the code and debug it.  Try returning \@all_questions or raising \@all_questions.inspect to see what \@all_questions gets loaded as.  Then do rand(@all_questions.size) until you figure out what is going on.